# Hyphen replaced by strange character in Android

Tags: java, android

I have some XML data coming in from an HttpPost, similar to this:

```
<Item>
  <Id>19695</Id>
  <Name>This is my content – it is great!</Name>
</Item>
```

and when I simply System.out.println the retrieved data, it prints this:

```
<Item>
  <Id>19695</Id>
  <Name>This is my content â it is great!</Name>
</Item>
```

So, when I check the XML in my browser, the hyphen "–" appears fine, but when I print it after doing the HttpPost, it is replaced with a "â"

I figure it has something to do with this code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                isr, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}
isr.close();

result = sb.toString();
```

How can I prevent this? Thanks!

EDIT: The same goes for apostrophes (')

Comment: set charset to UTF-8 while reading

Comment: @user3344236 this worked, if you post this as an answer I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set charset to UTF-8. Your reader must be set with UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an encoding problem. You are making an attempt to read as `iso-8859-1`. Are your server using other encoding (like `utf-8`)?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because you're not using the proper hyphen (perhaps due to an odd keyboard layout). Android supports HTML tags in strings so you might try putting `&#45;` in place of the hyphen.

Edit:

Here's the HTML tag for an apostrophe: `&#39;`

Comment: Also, set encoding to UTF-8.